# jQuery UI Themes which are totally different than what ThemeRoller gives

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Is anybody aware of a project/url that shares jQuery UI compatible themes, that you can't tell at first glance are from ThemeRoller. Difference: different icons, styling of tabs, dialogs etc, not just color palette. I think you got what I mean. ThemeRoller is nice but would be even nicer to have some visual alternatives. Even 1 would make a difference :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: btw a simple upload button on http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ would solve the whole issue...

Answer (score 7):

There's the '**Aristo**' JQuery UI theme: http://taitems.tumblr.com/post/482577430/introducing-aristo-a-jquery-ui-theme

Online demo here: http://www.warfuric.com/taitems/demo.html

In a nutshell, the author was fed up with the 'goofiness' of the Themeroller themes and wanted something closer to SproutCore and Cappuccino.

Answer (score 3):

No, as all the above items are customizable in the ui css file. I usually get it close, then make the necessary changes to the code.

The easiest way I have found to do this is by using firebug, and tweaking the css rules until I get what I am looking for. I then save those changes to the actual file (really easy as firebug gives you line numbers and class names).

EDIT: 
According to [this forum posting](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-ui-dev/browse_thread/thread/b8c530b57452d125?pli=1), in order to work with ie6, the icons have to be in a very specific format. The forum lists the format.

The good news is that it seems you can likely develop some customized icons in grayscale, and just dump them into the theme you are working on, or even perhaps replace a few of the icons.

Comment: I dont have problem with customization of stock themes, what I am interested in would be downloadable customized themes with custom icon sets etc.

Comment: Still not there :) I know how to customize a UI theme, done it quite a few times, my question is about a place where I could browse/discover themes (ala gnome-look ) that differ from default not just by color. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: I understand your dilemma. 
As I noted, I know of no such sources, and due to the time involved, I think it is unlikely they will pop up soon. therefore, I just want to try and give you as much help as I could if you were forced by necesity to do it yourself.

Comment: so you want custom-made, unique themes that are shared for free online so that anybody can use them - sounds like a bit of a contradiction in terms to me. Any themes that are shared and for free will end up seeming samey eventually.

Comment: @wheresrhys: I dont think themes on http://www.gnome-look.org/ or http://kde-look.org/ look anywhere near "looking same" while they are free & shared & custom, so cant agree with you. Thing like this should exist for jQuery UI as well.

Comment: @pentarim - why don't you develop a site to host alternative themes and get people to submit then, great side project idea!

Comment: It does exist in the sense that there is a themeroller at all.
We don't disagree that is would be great to have, but with the development pace of jquery, and the relative ease with doing it yourself (excepting the icons, which can be done using a specific format), I just don't see it happening. 
If you wanted to create a site, I'd try to contribute. However, what you are looking for does not currently exist.

Comment: @Fermin @Cryophallion - Thanks. I came to same idea yesterday as well so grabbed jqueryui-look.org, expect something there soon (will update on progress), need to check with UI team if its fine with them

Comment: @Pentarim - Bookmarking it now. Basically, the key change you want it to be able to try some new icons though, as that the is only thing you cannot easily do within customizing a theme in themeroller. Is that correct? Keep in mind that a great detail about customizing the theme with themeroller is that it provides a link with a get string with all the mods to it. That is invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

The link below is a theme plugin, seems to have some user updated themes.

http://keith-wood.name/themes.html

Comment: From what I saw this plugins tries to make easier the loading of a theme (including css worked just fine for me up to now), but doesnt provide new themes, just stock UI themes.

Answer (score 0):

Another jQuery UI theme with a more professional look,
as opposed to the (still!) goofy themeroller themes:

Absolution theme : http://www.michaelvanderheeren.be/?p=382

Answer (score 0):

**Color palette...** I have found it's fairly easy to create a custom theme to get the basic colors in place and then just tweak the css to change elements the theme builder doesn't address, i.e. padding, margins, border thickness, etc..

**Icons...** I looked around for some "plug and play" alternative icons for jquery-ui have found it easier to alter the original icon sprite in Photoshop. Jjust open one of the ui-icon_xxxxxx sprites and manually modify the icons to look how you want. You'll probably only want to tweak a few -- the arrows and check marks and maybe a few others -- so it's not a lot of work. Just keep each new icon centered within the 16 x 16 zone that each icon occupies on the icon sprite. They each take up far less than the full 16 x 16 pixels so you can make them much larger (relatively speaking). After you have all the icons looking how you want, erase the old icon underneath each one (obviously) then create an empty bg layer and merge your new layers with the original icon layer. Then create a solid color overlay layer and mask it to the icon layer. Then all you have to do is change the overlay color to 222222 and 454545 and 888888 (or whatever colors you want) and save-for-web each one over the old ones. Upload and BAM, they all work perfectly.